# Does “Microsoft Edge” and "Internet Explorer" use the same proxy settings?

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, windows-10, microsoft-edge, internet-options

Not really a "code" question, I'm building an app using "Edge" and "IE".
I need to change the proxy of those browsers to a custom one.

Does the "old internet options" windows that can be open through IE and by write "internet options" in the start windows changing the same "Connections->LAN settings" as the Edge/WIN10 new GUI proxy settings?

From a small testing that I preformed I can see that when I changes some values and save in one window and refresh the other one I can see the changes, Just want to make sure if it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes they are both getting proxy form internet option, you can change proxy setting even in new windows 10 modern setting under network and connection section.

Comment: Thanks,
B.T.W, you know where I can find an official statement from Microsoft for that?

Comment: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6263801-proxies